# Ambiguous C binding name in Fortran

Tags: linker, fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm trying to build and use a library from [this](https://github.com/SCM-NV/ftl) repo (FTL). FTL provides Fortran wrappers around POSIX regular expressions and can be built (according to its [wiki](https://github.com/SCM-NV/ftl/wiki/ftlRegex)) either using standard C library implementation from `<regex.h>` or PCRE implementation from `<pcreposix.h>`. I was able to successfully compile FTL's unit tests with `make test`, but their execution fails at runtime.

Here's what I think happens. The two implementations have different values of certain constants. These values are defined by execution of a C program (`configure/configure_ftlRegex.c`), where either `<pcreposix.h>` or `<regex.h>` is included, depending on macro definitions during compilation. By default (and this is how I compiled the unit tests) these constants are generated using the implementation from `<pcreposix.h>`.

Now, the following binding to a C function with name `regexec` is defined in `src/ftlRegex.F90`:

```
function C_regexec(preg, string, nmatch, pmatch, eflags) result(status) bind(C,name='regexec')
   import
   type(C_ptr)           , intent(in) , value :: preg
   character(kind=C_char), intent(in)         :: string(*)
   integer(C_size_t)     , intent(in) , value :: nmatch
   type(C_regmatch_t)    , intent(out)        :: pmatch(*)
   integer(C_int)        , intent(in) , value :: eflags
   integer(C_int)                             :: status
end function
```

However, there are two implementations of `regexec` available to the linker (with identical signatures): one from the standard C library (linked automatically), and another from `libpcreposix` (linked via `-lpcre -lpcreposix`). Which one does it actually bind to?

Executing `ldd tests` shows the following output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffd255a0000)
libgfortran.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.5 (0x00007f721a27c000)
libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f721a12d000)
libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7219f3b000)
libquadmath.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libquadmath.so.0 (0x00007f7219ef1000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7219ed6000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f721a647000)
```

As you can see, `libpcre` and `libpcreposix` are not on the list, which makes me believe that the linker chose to bind to the `<regex.h>` implementation, which is wrong because constants from `<pcreposix.h>` were used during the compilation. How does linker decide what implementation should be used in cases like this? Is there a way to enforce usage of particular implementation or at least check which implementation is used?

Note: The following command was used to link the unit tests (generated by makefile):

```
gfortran -std=f2008 -fall-intrinsics -ffree-line-length-none -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wno-target-lifetime -Wno-compare-reals -Jbuild.gnu.debug -g -Og -fcheck=bounds,do,mem,pointer,recursion -Isrc -Itests  -DUSE_PCRE tests/tests.F90 build.gnu.debug/*.o -lpcreposix -lpcre -o build.gnu.debug/tests
```

executed with GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2) 9.3.0.

Answer (score 0):

This does not really answer my original question, but, as a workaround, I ended up binding unambiguously to my own dummy C function, which, in turn, calls one or another implementation depending on which header is included by the preprocessor.